# Neo4j: Supply cypher parameters in web interface

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to pass parameters along with a cypher query via Neo4j's web interface or shell? For example, is it possible to get Neo4j's web interface to execute this statement?

```
return {test};
```

Running this statement in the web interface results in an error:

```
Expected a parameter named test
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
{ test: "foo" } // specify the parameters I would normally pass via the REST API

// my normal query
return {test};
```

Is there a way to do this? I want to do this because I'm using the REST API on Neo4j and all my queries take parameters. If I want to test any of my queries on the web interface or shell, I need to manually edit the query to replace the `{parameter}` markup with either `with` declarations or raw input. I'd like to be able to simply copy/paste my query as-is into the web interface, supplying a set of parameters and have it work.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible in the shell, all "environment" variables are available as parameters.

so if you do:

```
export test="foo"
return {test} as t;
+-------+
| t     |
+-------+
| "foo" |
+-------+
```

You can see all environment variables with `env`

Unfortunately not possible in the browser yet, it would be cool to have, 
perhaps with a tampermonkey / a chrome plugin.

Comment: This functionality has been added to Neo4j-browser, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397773/neo4j-what-is-the-syntax-to-set-cypher-query-parameters-in-the-browser-interfac  (and especially Michael's comment)