# neo4j: What is the syntax to set cypher query parameters in the browser interface?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to run queries from the neo4j browser to reproduce results from my neo4j-javascript-driver client.

What is the syntax for defining query parameters in the neo4j b

I recently attended a neo4j training session in NYC where the trainer (David Fauth) did this, unfortunately, I did not take notes on it, since I figured that I could read-up on this online...but no success.

Comment: I recently attended a neo4j training session in NYC where the trainer (David Fauth) did this, unfortunately, I did not take notes on it, since I figured that I could read-up on this online...the question you referenced was from 2015.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In neo4j-browser you need type for example:

```
:params {nodes: [{name: "John", age: 18}, {name: "Phill", age: 23}]}
```

Then you can use params as usual:

```
UNWIND {nodes} as node
MERGE (A:User {name: node.name, age: node.age})
RETURN A
```

For clear params in neo4j-browser type `:params {}`.

For additional help type `:help params`.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: you can also use `:param name: value` where value can be any valid json

Comment: What version did this feature release with?

Comment: This doesn't support nested properties. For example this will fail: `:params {"uidLeft": "asdf1", "uidRight": "asdf2", "type": "KNOWS", props:{uid:"rel1"}}`

Comment: @Clintm  What version are you using? I tried your example on version 3.2.1 (community) and everything works fine.

Comment: Asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244571/unable-to-set-nested-parameters-through-the-neo4j-browser-with-version-3-2-2

Comment: This fails for me with Neo4j 3.3.4:

`:params {
location:{latitude:42.3600825,longitude:-71.0588801}
}`

Comment: @Jackpile remove the { after params and } in the end of the line

Comment: with the latest neo4j 4.3.7, accessing params via { } is depreciated, and instead of you can use $. The same code can be rewritten as  `UNWIND $nodes as node
MERGE (A:User {name: node.name, age: node.age})
RETURN A`

Answer (score 10):

In Neo4j-3.3.4, the cypher likes this:

```
:param nodes: [{name: 'John', age: 18}, {name: 'Phill', age: 23}]
```

Neo4j Browser result:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zPm3.png)

Comment: Now this is recommended answer. `params` seems to be a footgun.

Comment: Still true for neo4j-3.5.8. But it's only in Neo4j Browser docs, and mentioned nowhere in Cypher doc or Cypher spec. Any clue _where_ this is suppoced be be specified?

Answer (score 2):

In Neo4j Browser 3.5+ you can use the Cypher Shell parameter syntax, documented here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell-parameters

```
:param name => expression
```

The expression must be kept on a single line.

The expression could be a scalar or a list:

```
:param foo => ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Maps can't be used directly with this syntax as of Neo4j 4.1. You can wrap them into a list:

```
:param foo => [{name: 'Alice', age: 38, address: {city: 'London', residential: true}}]
```

Or you can use `:params`:

```
:params {foo: {name: 'Alice', age: 38, address: {city: 'London', residential: true}}}
```

Comment: This is only true for single values. For objects, Neo4j Browser still requires you to use the syntax in the accepted answer.

Comment: It works for lists as well. Not for maps though, although I can wrap a map inside a list, e,g,: `:param foo => [{name: 'Alice', age: 38, address: {city: 'London', residential: true}}]`. I've updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j Browser 3.5+ you can use

```
:params param_name => 'param_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic cases:

1. Set singe variable value *mytext="Hello"*: `:param mytext => "Hello"`
2. set dictionary values *attr={"oid":1, "text":"Hello"}*:
   `:param attr => ({oid: 1, text:"Hello"})`

Cypher usage:

1. `MATCH (x) WHERE x.a = $mytext RETURN x`
2. set a value `MATCH (x) WHERE x.a = $attr.oid SET x.b = $attr.text`
3. set multiple values `MATCH (x) WHERE ... SET x = $attr`