# Neo4j Browser syntax for Cypher query parameters

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

What is the syntax for passing a parameter to a Cypher query when using the Neo4j Browser?

Specifically, how would you pass a list of dictionaries to execute [example 3.3.6.4](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-create-nodes-from-a-list-parameter) from the documentation in the neo4j browser?

Comment: Are you looking for what is explained in :help params ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [neo4j: What is the syntax to set cypher query parameters in the browser interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397773/neo4j-what-is-the-syntax-to-set-cypher-query-parameters-in-the-browser-interfac)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @TomGeudens indicated, you can use `:help param` and `:help params` in the neo4j browser to see the relevant browser commands.

In your specific example, you can use this browser command to create the `$events` parameter:

```
:param events: [{year: 2014, id: 1}, {year: 2014, id: 2}]
```