# Unable to set nested parameters through the neo4j browser with version 3.2.2

Tags: neo4j

I've opened the neo4j browser and tried to run the following query:

```
:params {"uidLeft": "asdf1", "uidRight": "asdf2", "type": "KNOWS", props:{uid:"rel1"}}
```

And I get the following error:

> Could not parse input. Usage: `:param "x": 2`. SyntaxError: Expected ",", "}" or key but "{" found.

Are nested properties supposed to be supported?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the outer parenthesis, that shouldn't be needed:

```
:params "uidLeft": "asdf1", "uidRight": "asdf2", "type": "KNOWS", props:{uid:"rel1"}
```

Comment: What should be the syntax if the parameter is a list? i.e. a list of ID `MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.ID IN {id_list} RETURN *`?

Comment: You can use `[ ]` to designate a list.

Comment: I tried `:params  id_list:{['123','124',125']}; MATCH p WHERE p.ID IN {id_list} RETURN *; ` but i'm still getting an error

Comment: You don't need that outer pair of `{}`. Just use `:params id_list:['123','124',125']`

Comment: Tried your suggestion but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: There's also a missing quote on the last entry, that could be it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158812/discussion-between-joseph-berry-and-inversefalcon).

Comment: found the correct syntax `:para {idlist:['123','124','125']}`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Neo4j Browser 3.0.5, the version that are shipped with Neo4j 3.2.2 and 3.2.3.

Running the following command (with outer parenthesis) in Neo4j Browser 3.0.4 (Neo4j 3.2.1) all works fine:

```
:params {"uidLeft": "asdf1", "uidRight": "asdf2", "type": "KNOWS", props:{uid:"rel1"}}
```

But the command indicated by @InverseFalcon (without outer parenthesis) don't work for Neo4j Browser 3.0.4 (Neo4j 3.2.1), only for Neo4j Browser 3.0.5:

```
:params "uidLeft": "asdf1", "uidRight": "asdf2", "type": "KNOWS", props:{uid:"rel1"}
```

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/645) in the Neo4j Browser repo.