# How to pass multiple parameters to the Neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser, cypher-shell

I'd like to pass multiple parameters to the Neo4j 4.0 browser while making sure that the type of the parameter values (int, date) is interpreted correctly.
I tried using the syntax of the [Cypher shell commands](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/tools/cypher-shell/):

1. Using the colon syntax `paramName: paramValue` allows passing multiple parameters but their type is implicitly converted (date to string, integer to float):

   ```
   :param d: date('2020-03-07'), x: 1
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   {
     "d": "date('2020-03-07')",
     "x": 1.0
   }
   ```
2. Using the arrow syntax, I can define the both parameters correctly but it requires separate `:param` commands:

   ```
   :param d => date('2020-03-07')
   :param x => 1
   :params
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   {
     "d": "2020-03-07",
     "x": 1
   }
   ```

Many of my queries use a large number of parameters -- it there a way to pass all parameters correctly using a single command?

(There is a related question, [neo4j: What is the syntax to set cypher query parameters in the browser interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397773/neo4j-what-is-the-syntax-to-set-cypher-query-parameters-in-the-browser-interfac), however, answers do not consider the issues regarding types.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create multiple parameters with the correct types in a single `:param` command using "destructuring".

For example, to get `d` and `x` with the correct types:

```
:param [{d, x}] => {RETURN date('2020-03-07') AS d, 1 AS x}
```

Use the `:help params` command in the browser to get some more information.

Comment: nice answer @cybersam